# Enter timestamp in a cell when a dropdown box in another cell is updated (no VBA)

Tags: timestamp

I need to enter a timestamp in a cell when a dropdown box in another cell is updated. This is for a live In/Out board spreadsheet, so apparently I cannot use macros.

Right now I have the formula set to:

```
=IF(D3="","",IF(H3="",NOW(),H3))
```

The timestamp looks great but only updates when used the first time or if the user deletes their status in the "Availability" column, then chooses another option in the drop down box (they cannot simply choose a new option in the drop down box or the "Last Update" column does not update). Is there a way to accomplish what I need without the use of macros?

Does anyone know if macros work with co-authored spreadsheets?

Comment: No, you cannot update one cell (with an unrelated value) by updating another cell without macros. (Can you edit and explain more why macros is not an option?)

Comment: I tried using macros and it worked beautifully until I made the spreadsheet live. I read that macros are not supported in live spreadsheets.

Comment: Do you know if macros work with co-authored spreadsheets?

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean by "live spreadsheets', please be more detailed.

Comment: Excel for the web. I am sharing this with co-workers. I also tried to make it a co-authored spreadsheet. After extensive research, it appears my macro will not work at all when shared.

Comment: Indeed, Excel for the web doesn't support macros. Perhaps you can check out if you can do something like this using the Office Scripts in Excel (which does work for Excel for the web) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel